# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError - Expected OAuth 2 access token

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, service-accounts, google-api-dotnet-client

We are getting the following error in c# when executing Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.StopRequest.Stop.  **NOTE:  this is code that has ran for 2+ years and suddenly stopped working around 3/23/2022.  I am also including a screenshot of the Nuget versions we are using.  Any advice or direction on this is appreciated!

[image: Google.Apis Nugets]

### THE CODE:

```
 var credential = GetCredential(serviceAccountEmail, certFileName, email);

            if (credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
            {
                var accessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
                GmailService gmailService = new GmailService(
                    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential

                    }
                );

                var stopRequest = gmailService.Users.Stop(email);

                stopRequestStatus = stopRequest.Execute();

            }
```

This is the code for GetCredentials:

```
ServiceAccountCredential GetCredential(string serviceAccountEmail, string certFileName, string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            log.Debug("svcAacntEmail=" + serviceAccountEmail);
            log.Debug("Userid=" + userId);
            log.Debug("certfilename" + certFileName);

            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFileName, SvcResource.CERT_PASSWORD, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);


            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                       new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                       {
                           User = userId,
                           Scopes = new[] 
                             { 
                                 "https://mail.google.com/",
                              
                             }
                       }.FromCertificate(certificate));


            return credential;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error in setting creds for gmail svc auth", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

### THE ERROR:

The service gmail has thrown an exception:

> Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
> Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [401]
> Errors [
> Message[Invalid Credentials] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[authError] Domain[global]
> ]

> at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ParseResponse>d__31.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()

Comment: I would check the workspace account make sure your service account still has domain wide delegation set up.   Looks like someone may have changed something.

Comment: We run this code for several instances of workspace and it is happening in several of them.

Comment: Can you confirm that the access token you are using is still valid? In addition to this, can you check that the credentials match with the ones from the service account and that DWD is still enabled?

Comment: @ale the client library they are doing handles all that internally.  Its not something that they can check.  If the access token is in valid then the library should be refreshing it.   As this is a service account the refresh again is done internally within the library.

Comment: @Andy can you post your code for GetCredential?

Comment: @DalmTo.  Thank you for looking at this.   I added the method to my original post above.

Comment: Also note, this is a production account that has been working for several years & all of them coincidentally stopped 3/23 - 3/25 timeframe

Comment: Theres someone else getting this same error https://stackoverflow.com/q/71695932/1841839 i have sent a ping off to the oauth team to see if they know anything about this.

Comment: FYI - I've raised an Issue Tracker ticket here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/227875476

Comment: Can you reproduce this without a service account? I think the best solution in this situation is to contact Workspace Support directly by choosing one of the options [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) as they can provide a more accurate assessment of the reason this is not working as you'd like it to.

Comment: @Andy can you please create an issue on the [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). Mention my name (Amanda Tarafa) there so I can get notified or post the link to the issue here. We are looking into this but we need more info from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[I ran into this issue as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71695932/1841839) in our C# application.

I've now figured out the problem - and it's nothing to do with what the 401 error message suggests.

Our application is written in C# and is attempting to use TLS 1.0 by default. When we force it to use TLS 1.2, it works absolutely fine.

So the real problem is the cryptography ciphers used in the HTTPS connection and is nothing to do with the Authorization header, etc.