# Gmail API - has something changed permissions wise for government accounts?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

We've had tens of thousands of users using our app that integrates with the Gmail API for 7 years or so, however in the past week or so we've suddenly seen widespread failures (401 responses), but **only for government customers based in the US**.

I've managed to obtain a trace from one of our customers of the HTTP traffic between our app and the Gmail server:

**Request**

I have abbreviated the access token here for brevity / security, but I have confirmed the actual value in the header matches the access token received from Google. I have also abbreviated the multipart MIME message and changed the customer's email address.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="f31e2e89cedf4242be6fcbe5e793173e"
User-Agent: Affixa Enterprise 1.2021.3.15
Authorization: Bearer ya29.A0ARrdaM8v6BZrUpbTJb...N2wbiX8Ej9vY
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 8249
Expect: 100-continue

--f31e2e89cedf4242be6fcbe5e793173e
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{}
--f31e2e89cedf4242be6fcbe5e793173e
Content-Type: message/rfc822

MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: Affixa Enterprise 1.2021.3.15
From: foo@bar.gov
Subject: LogCrossSearchResult_22A0XSR5009663_2022-03-23-15-13.csv
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 10:39:19 -0500
Message-ID: <1.6139e48b20e838d93825@msg.affixa.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_001_2C7F_AA3B1314.8E6FEB65"


------=_NextPart_001_2C7F_AA3B1314.8E6FEB65
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_1462_A4B24415.C610B984"


------=_NextPart_000_1462_A4B24415.C610B984
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-GUploader-UploadID: ADPycdsnG_KOSQm3Cok7zCHHavR5wr0elW-o3cMbzRCP2OGTULeAdvCIbIQ7xFF6MCf7EAsBrjzNI-TBVa_5spdFcnLGQyFNPQ
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 507
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2022 15:39:19 GMT
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Nothing has changed in the software or with our application's registration in the Google Developer Console.

FWIW, our application hasn't been reviewed by Google, however neither does it need to be as business-facing application that's installed from the Workspace Marketplace. The application can only be used by an entire Workspace organisation and installed by an Admin; it can't be installed on a per-user basis.

The customer has confirmed that all the required scopes are still granted:

[image: Customer settings in Admin Portal]

Has something changed that I'm not aware of?

Comment: you are the second i have seen with this error today  here is the other https://stackoverflow.com/q/71691019/1841839  I have sent off a ping to someone on the Oauth team to see if they know anything about this.   Your using a service account correct with domain wide delegation?

Comment: Yes, that’s the case. Though I believe we’re also seeing it with a normal client with a client secret too.

Comment: As suggested by [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto), It would be worth to report this in the [Issuetracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) or contact [developer support from Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6103110) to investigate this behavior as your application has been working for a reasonable amount of time and now you are receiving this error with an specific type of Google Workspace account.

Comment: Thanks - have raised this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/227875476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now figured out the problem - and it's *nothing* to do with what the 401 error message suggests.

Our application is written in C# and is attempting to use TLS 1.0 by default. When we force it to use TLS 1.2, it works absolutely fine.

So the real problem is the cryptography ciphers used in the HTTPS connection and is nothing to do with the Authorization header, etc.

I'm guessing non-governmental accounts are still OK with TLS 1.0 for the moment?